# Jquery Sortable passing values to java controller

Tags: java, jquery, ajax

Im trying to pass the values to the controller but the ajax part isn't working it is not getting submitted to the controller.

```
$("#sortable").sortable({
   update: function(event, ui) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:  "reordertable.html",
            data: {
                "rid" : "${table.rowid}",
                "productid" : "${productid}",
                "newIndex" : ui.item.index()
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Here I dont use any form I have a table in which the .
any suggestions please.

Comment: Code looks good. It is POSTing as expected. Your error might be elsewhere. http://jsfiddle.net/oqt2b0jh/